# Combining USA + Canada (specific provinces) with Plotly (plot_geo) or ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly

I'm building a simple app for showing some results me and my research group obtained in the past few months. 
Data are from specific states of USA and provinces of Canada. 
 I'd like to incorporate data from Alberta and Ontario provinces within the North America map but, when dealing with `locationmode =` in `plot_geo` function, I'm not able to combine them with the data from the USA states. 
 Here are attached the developed app and an example of the data we have.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

data<-read.csv(file="data.csv",header=TRUE,sep=";")
head(data)
data$results <- with(data,paste("% of subjects",'<br>', "State:",data$States_Extended, 
                                '<br>', "Nr. of Samples:", data$Samples))
numbers <- paste("State:",data$States_Extended, '<br>',
                 "Nr. of Samples:", data$Samples)


ui1 <- fluidPage(
 titlePanel("Map of Positive Findings"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("variable", "Choose a target variable",
                  c("variable1" = "variable1",
                    "variable2" = "variable2")),
      radioButtons("maps", "Select type of data:",
                   c("Number of samples" = "samples",
                     "% of subjects" = "target"))),

    mainPanel(
     h3(textOutput("caption")),
      plotlyOutput("MapPlot"),
      fluidRow(
        DT::dataTableOutput("datatable")
      )
    )
  )
)




server1 <- function(input, output) {

  # Compute the formula text ----
  # This is in a reactive expression since it is shared by the
  # output$caption and output$mpgPlot functions
  formulaText <- reactive({
    paste("You chose: Map of", input$variable)
  })

  # Return the formula text for printing as a caption ----
  output$caption <- renderText({
    formulaText()
  })

  datasetInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$variable,
           "variable1" = data[,c("States_Extended","variable1")],
           "variable2" = data[,c("States_Extended","variable2")]
           )
  })
  output$datatable <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datasetInput()
  })
# Generate a plot of the requested variable against mpg ----
  # and only exclude outliers if requested
  output$MapPlot <- renderPlotly({
    # give state boundaries a border
    l <- list(color = toRGB("white"), width = 1)
    # specify some map projection/options
    g <- list(
      scope = 'north america',
      projection = list(type = 'albers'),
      showland = TRUE,
      landcolor = toRGB('grey'),
      showlakes = TRUE,
      lakecolor = toRGB('blue'),
      landcolor = toRGB("gray95"),
      subunitcolor = toRGB("gray85"),
      countrycolor = toRGB("gray85"),
      countrywidth = 0.5,
      subunitwidth = 0.5  
    )
    maps <- switch(input$maps,
                   samples = plot_geo(data, locationmode = 'USA-states',
                                      marker = list(line = l)) %>%
                     add_trace(
                       z = ~Samples, text = numbers, locations = ~States,
                       color = ~Samples, colors = 'Reds'
                     ) %>%
                     colorbar(title = paste('Number of <br>','analysis')) %>%
                     layout(
                       title = paste('Number of samples'),
                       geo = g
                     ),
                   target = plot_geo(data, locationmode = 'USA-states',
                                     marker = list(line = l)) %>%
                     add_trace(
                       z = ~data[,input$variable], text = ~results, locations = ~States,
                       color = ~data[,input$variable], colors = 'Oranges'
                     ) %>%
                     colorbar(title = paste(input$variable,'%')) %>%
                     layout(
                       title = paste('% of subjects  <br>', input$variable),
                       geo = g
                     )
    )

  })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui1, server = server1)
```

And the related data:

```
structure(list(States = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 
22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 
35L, 36L, 37L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 
49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 1L, 38L), .Label = c("AB", "AK", "AL", "AR", 
"AZ", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "FL", "GA", "HI", "IA", "ID", "IL", 
"IN", "KS", "KY", "LA", "MA", "MD", "ME", "MI", "MN", "MO", "MS", 
"MT", "NC", "ND", "NE", "NH", "NJ", "NM", "NV", "NY", "OH", "OK", 
"ON", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "VA", "VT", 
"WA", "WI", "WV", "WY"), class = "factor"), States_Extended = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 16L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
17L, 18L, 19L, 22L, 21L, 20L, 23L, 24L, 26L, 25L, 27L, 34L, 35L, 
28L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 29L, 33L, 36L, 37L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 
44L, 45L, 46L, 48L, 47L, 49L, 51L, 50L, 52L, 3L, 38L), .Label = c("Alabama", 
"Alaska", "Alberta", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", 
"Connecticut", "Delaware", "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", 
"Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", 
"Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", 
"Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", 
"New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", 
"Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Ontario", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", 
"South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", 
"Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", 
"Wyoming"), class = "factor"), Samples = c(1L, 2L, 0L, 14L, 4L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 12L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 25L, 3L, 
4L, 0L, 8L, 1L, 6L, 0L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 
1L), variable1 = c(0L, 50L, NA, 64L, 0L, 50L, 100L, 50L, 100L, 
57L, NA, 50L, NA, NA, 100L, NA, 33L, 50L, NA, NA, NA, 100L, 50L, 
50L, 100L, 100L, 60L, NA, 0L, NA, 75L, 75L, 100L, 72L, 100L, 
50L, NA, 63L, 100L, 50L, NA, 50L, 57L, 75L, 100L, NA, NA, 0L, 
NA, NA, 100L, 100L), variable2 = c(0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 29L, NA, 0L, NA, NA, 17L, NA, 17L, 0L, NA, NA, NA, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 20L, NA, 0L, NA, 25L, 25L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 0L, NA, 
0L, 0L, 17L, NA, 0L, 14L, 0L, 40L, NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, 0L, 0L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -52L))
```

I attach here also an example of the current developed app:

[Example of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhr5t.jpg)

Comment: Can you add your dataset to your post using `dput()`?

Comment: Dear @MLavoie, I tried but I failed to do it. Can't you manage the dataset if reported this way? Sorry for my low skills...!

Comment: In R, just type: dput(yourdataset) and copy the content in your post.

Comment: Dear @MLavoie, I followed your indication and updated the post, hope it helps! Thanks for your willingness, btw!

Comment: This might help https://community.plot.ly/t/choropleth-of-a-country-distinct-than-usa/4741. The Canadian provinces are not recognized in `locationmode = 'USA-states'`.

Comment: Thank you @MLavoie, I had already found that post but I couldn't deal with it correctly! Btw, thanks for your suggestion!